# Evitar que se concatene el puerto al usar rutas relativas para mostrar imágenes

Tags: html, imagen, rutas, puertos

tengo un proyecto en el cual se muestran imágenes, pero tengo un problema con las rutas. Si uso rutas relativas al mostrarlo en el navegador me concatena el puerto y la ip en el que está alojado ese proyecto, pero yo tengo las imágenes alojadas sobre otro puerto.

Por ejemplo, he intentado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los que hace que busque en http://10.255.245.76/ticketresource/img/imagen.jpg, pero necesito que le agregue el puerto 8090 después de la ip, así que intenté concatenárselo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero va a buscar la imagen de la siguiente manera: http://10.255.245.76/:8090/ticketresource/img/imagen.jpg

Y necesito que quede: http://10.255.245.76:8090/ticketresource/img/imagen.jpg

Agradecería alguna respuesta.

Comment: Para utilizar un recurso de un puerto diferente de 80, debes agregar la ruta completa.

Comment: El erroe es que usas una url relativa. al poner el puerto como prefijo, el intérprete no sabe que quieres hacer y **completa la dirección** debes poner una dirección absoluta (ej: `<img ... src="http://10.255.245.76:8090/ticketresource/img/imagen.jpg" ...>` de modo que el intérprete la toma tal cual la escribiste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás planteando una pregunta de lo que se llama el [problema xy](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3360/21), comenzaré por responder lo que estás preguntando:

**No puedes escribir una ruta relativa que incluya el puerto, o cualquier otro elemento antes de la carpeta raíz del servidor web al que pertenece tu página**.

En otras palabras: No puedes utilizar rutas relativas para lo que quieres lograr. (de allí la referencia al problema XY).

### Hablemos de rutas relativas

Para obtener cualquier recurso, una ruta relativa significa justamente que comparte *la raíz* de la ruta del recurso que le hace referencia.

Hablando de [URL's](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localizador_de_recursos_uniforme), lo más lejos que puedes llegar con una rutas relativas es a la carpeta raíz, que está más allá del dominio y de la posible especificación del puerto.

Si tu página está en la ruta:

```
https://www.midominio.com:9972/carpeta1/pagina2.html
```

Cualquier ruta relativa que escribas dentro del HTML de dicha página partirá de     `https://www.midominio.com:9972/carpeta1/` si la ruta no inicia con `/`, o de `https://www.midominio.com:9972/` si la ruta inicia con `/`.

Esto tiene sentido, y es que cualquier ruta que no inicie con `https://www.midominio.com:9972/`, en realidad, pertenece a otro servidor/servicio, y por tanto, no es *relativa* a `https://www.midominio.com:9972/`.

### Hablando de tu problema

Entiendo que tu:

- Tienes dos servidores web que tienen la misma estructura de carpetas, y quieres referenciar, en las páginas servidas por el primero, recursos ubicados en el segundo.
- Estas escribiendo páginas que, o bien se instalarán en distintos dominios/servidores y por tanto quieres una solución que se *adapte* a la dirección donde se obtuvo la página, ya que, en cualquier otro caso, sería mejor escribir rutas absolutas en cada imagen.

No puedes hacer esto con puro HTML, pero si pones un poco de javascript, podrías lograrlo (hasta cierta medida).

Por ejemplo, con javascript puro, puedes ponerle un `id` a cada imagen y valerte de ese `id` para ponerle, ya en tiempo de corrida, la dirección de la imagen, tirando también de los atributos de [window.location](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp), para obtener los datos de la URL desde donde se cargó la página, un ejemplo sencillo luciría como este:

```js
  function ponerruta(imagen) {
    result = window.location.protocol 
           + "//"
           + window.location.hostname
           + ":4450"
           + "/imagenes/" + imagen;
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
  
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("img1").src = ponerruta("imagen.jpeg");
  };
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="/img/placeholder.jpeg"/>
```

Con esto, tendrías que tener una única imagen en `/img/placeholder.jpeg` para que se muestre *mientras* se cargan las imágenes reales, proceso que comenzaría una vez se haya cargado la página completa en el navegador.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me funcionó! Y gracias por lo del problema xy, realmente no tenía idea.